# why mhy bucket namespace is not shown in amazon consolse but certanly exists?

Tags: amazon-s3, bucket

I have a bucket created since mid 2010. The bucket exists but is empty. Last night the bucked disappeared from the amazon console. The weird thing is that the bucket is visible when I browse using S3 organizer on Firefox

Also I have two Access Credentials created but I can only see the bucket using one of them. When I try to create the bucket using the account where the bucket is not present i get the following message

> The requested bucket name is not available. The bucket namespace is
>   shared by all users of the system. Please select a different name and
>   try again.

which make no sense to me because I know I'm the owner of the bucket and is being shown with the other Access Credential

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. looks like was a AWS cache issue. I deleted the bucket and created it again.